# UIAlertViewController's alert modal cannot be dismissed by adding UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, objective-c

I almost read all related articles here but still cannot get the alert dismissed. Can anyone help? It shouldn't be that hard...

P.S. in the defaultAction callback, I tried both:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                                                                  NSLog(@"ok...");
                                                              }];
```

and

```
NSLog(@"ok...");
```

Both are out of luck

My code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIAlertController *alert;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                                   message:@""
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    self.alert = alert;
    self.alert.message = @"You just logged in. The tab will be refreshed";
    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                              [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                                                                  NSLog(@"webview is reloading...");
                                                              }];

                                                          }];

    [self.alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:self.alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: It turns out it is the iOS simulator's issue. it works fine with NSLog(@"ok..."); solution on device. Submitting issue to Apple now...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is primarily a bug from Apple. I will open a tech support ticket with them ASAP. Before I got further info, I will close this question for now.

Answer (score 1):

It will dismiss it self.If you

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
              NSLog(@"webview is reloading...");
          }];
```

use then it will dismiss the your current View contrtoller where alert controller present after dismiss it show the Log.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
      UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Reminder" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
     self.alert = alert;
     self.alert.message = @"You just logged in. The tab will be refreshed";
                UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) 
          {
                    NSLog(@"Ok button pressed..");      
                    NSLog(@"webview is reloading...");
         }];
   }];
    [self.alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:self.alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close. you just have to make a slight adjustment.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                                   message:@"You just logged in. The tab will be refreshed"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
//alert dismisses itself
     }];

    [self.alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:self.alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```